# Python, lambda function as argument for groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure out what a piece of code is doing, but I'm getting kinda lost on it.

I have a pandas dataframe, which has been loaded by the following .csv file:

```
origin_census_block_group,date_range_start,date_range_end,device_count,distance_traveled_from_home,bucketed_distance_traveled,median_dwell_at_bucketed_distance_traveled,completely_home_device_count,median_home_dwell_time,bucketed_home_dwell_time,at_home_by_each_hour,part_time_work_behavior_devices,full_time_work_behavior_devices,destination_cbgs,delivery_behavior_devices,median_non_home_dwell_time,candidate_device_count,bucketed_away_from_home_time,median_percentage_time_home,bucketed_percentage_time_home,mean_home_dwell_time,mean_non_home_dwell_time,mean_distance_traveled_from_home
010539707003,2020-06-25T00:00:00-05:00,2020-06-26T00:00:00-05:00,49,626,"{""16001-50000"":5,""0"":11,"">50000"":4,""2001-8000"":3,""1-1000"":9,""1001-2000"":7,""8001-16000"":1}","{""16001-50000"":110,"">50000"":155,""<1000"":40,""2001-8000"":237,""1001-2000"":27,""8001-16000"":180}",12,627,"{""721-1080"":11,""361-720"":9,""61-360"":1,""<60"":11,"">1080"":12}","[32,32,28,30,30,31,27,23,20,20,20,17,19,19,15,14,17,20,20,21,25,22,24,23]",7,3,"{""120330012011"":1,""010030107031"":1,""010030114052"":2,""120330038001"":1,""010539701003"":1,""010030108001"":1,""010539707002"":14,""010539705003"":2,""120330015001"":1,""121130102003"":1,""010539701002"":1,""120330040001"":1,""370350101014"":2,""120330033081"":2,""010030106003"":1,""010539706001"":2,""010539707004"":3,""120330039001"":1,""010539699003"":1,""120330030003"":1,""010539707003"":41,""010970029003"":1,""010539705004"":1,""120330009002"":1,""010539705001"":3,""010539704003"":1,""120330028012"":1,""120330035081"":1,""120330036102"":1,""120330036142"":1,""010030114062"":1,""010539706004"":7,""010539706002"":1,""120330036082"":1,""010539707001"":7,""010030102001"":1,""120330028011"":1}",2,241,71,"{""21-45"":4,""481-540"":2,""541-600"":1,""721-840"":1,""1201-1320"":1,""301-360"":3,""<20"":13,""61-120"":3,""241-300"":3,""121-180"":1,""421-480"":3,""1321-1440"":4,""1081-1200"":1,""961-1080"":2,""601-660"":1,""181-240"":1,""661-720"":2,""361-420"":3}",72,"{""0-25"":13,""76-100"":21,""51-75"":6,""26-50"":3}",657,413,1936
010730144081,2020-06-25T00:00:00-05:00,2020-06-26T00:00:00-05:00,139,2211,"{""16001-50000"":17,""0"":41,"">50000"":15,""2001-8000"":22,""1-1000"":8,""1001-2000"":12,""8001-16000"":24}","{""16001-50000"":143,"">50000"":104,""<1000"":132,""2001-8000"":39,""1001-2000"":15,""8001-16000"":102}",41,806,"{""721-1080"":32,""361-720"":16,""61-360"":12,""<60"":30,"">1080"":46}","[91,92,93,91,91,90,86,83,78,64,64,61,64,62,65,62,60,74,61,64,75,78,81,84]",8,6,"{""131350501064"":1,""131350502151"":1,""010730102002"":1,""011170302131"":2,""010730038024"":1,""010730108041"":1,""010730144133"":1,""010730132003"":1,""011210118002"":1,""011170303053"":1,""010730111084"":2,""011170302142"":1,""010730119011"":1,""010730129063"":2,""010730107063"":1,""010730059083"":1,""010730058003"":1,""011270204003"":1,""010730049012"":2,""130879701001"":1,""010730120021"":1,""130890219133"":1,""010730144082"":4,""170310301031"":1,""010730129112"":1,""010730024002"":1,""011170303034"":2,""481390616004"":1,""121270826052"":1,""010730128021"":2,""121270825073"":1,""010730004004"":1,""211959313002"":1,""010730100012"":1,""011170302151"":1,""010730142041"":1,""010730129123"":1,""010730129084"":1,""010730042002"":1,""010730059033"":2,""170318306001"":1,""130519800001"":1,""010730027003"":1,""121270826042"":1,""481610001002"":1,""010730100011"":1,""010730023032"":1,""350250004002"":1,""010730056003"":1,""010730132001"":1,""011170302171"":2,""120910227003"":1,""011239620001"":1,""130351503002"":1,""010730129155"":1,""010730001001"":2,""010730110021"":1,""170310104003"":1,""010730059082"":2,""010730120022"":1,""011170303151"":1,""010730139022"":1,""011170303441"":4,""010730144092"":3,""010730129151"":1,""011210119001"":2,""010730144081"":117,""010730108052"":1,""010730129122"":9,""370710321003"":1,""010730142034"":2,""010730042001"":2,""010570201003"":1,""010730144132"":6,""010730059032"":1,""010730012001"":2,""010730102003"":1,""011170303332"":1,""010730128032"":2,""010730129081"":1,""010730103011"":1,""010730058001"":3,""011150401041"":1,""010730045001"":3,""010730110013"":1,""010730119041"":1,""010730042003"":1,""010730141041"":1,""010730144091"":1,""010730129154"":1,""484759501002"":1,""010730144063"":1,""010730144102"":12,""011170303141"":1,""011250106011"":1,""011170303152"":1,""010730059104"":1,""010730107021"":1,""010730100014"":1,""010730008004"":1,""011170303451"":1,""010730127041"":2,""370559704003"":1,""010730047011"":2,""010730129132"":2,""011010014002"":1,""010730144131"":1,""011170302133"":1,""010730030011"":1,""131350506063"":1,""010730118023"":1,""010890110141"":1,""010730128023"":1,""010730106022"":2,""130879703004"":1,""010730108015"":1,""131390010041"":1,""011170305013"":1,""010730134002"":1,""010730031004"":1,""010730138012"":1,""010730011004"":1,""011250102041"":1,""010730129131"":4,""010730144101"":4,""011170303331"":2,""010730003001"":1,""011010033012"":1,""483539504004"":1,""010550104021"":1,""011170303411"":1,""010730106031"":1,""011170303153"":5,""010730128034"":1,""010730129061"":1,""131390010023"":1,""010730051042"":1,""130510107002"":1,""010730027001"":2,""120090686011"":1,""010730107042"":1,""010730123052"":1,""010730129102"":1,""011210115003"":1,""010730129083"":4,""011170303142"":1,""011010014001"":1,""010730107064"":2}",7,176,205,"{""21-45"":7,""481-540"":10,""541-600"":4,""46-60"":2,""721-840"":3,""1201-1320"":3,""301-360"":7,""<20"":46,""61-120"":6,""241-300"":4,""121-180"":9,""421-480"":2,""1321-1440"":3,""1081-1200"":5,""961-1080"":1,""601-660"":1,""181-240"":5,""661-720"":1,""361-420"":7}",78,"{""0-25"":29,""76-100"":71,""51-75"":27,""26-50"":8}",751,338,38937
010890017002,2020-06-25T00:00:00-05:00,2020-06-26T00:00:00-05:00,78,1934,"{""16001-50000"":2,""0"":12,"">50000"":9,""2001-8000"":27,""1-1000"":12,""1001-2000"":8,""8001-16000"":8}","{""16001-50000"":49,"">50000"":99,""<1000"":111,""2001-8000"":37,""1001-2000"":24,""8001-16000"":28}",11,787,"{""721-1080"":17,""361-720"":11,""61-360"":11,""<60"":15,"">1080"":23}","[49,42,48,48,47,48,44,44,39,32,34,32,36,31,32,36,40,37,36,38,49,45,46,46]",5,1,"{""010890101002"":1,""010730108041"":1,""010890020003"":2,""010890010001"":2,""010890025011"":3,""010890026001"":4,""280819505003"":1,""281059504004"":1,""010890103022"":1,""120990056011"":1,""010890109012"":2,""010890019021"":6,""010890013021"":4,""010890015004"":3,""010890108003"":1,""010890014022"":6,""281059501003"":1,""281059503001"":1,""010890007022"":3,""010890017001"":3,""010890107023"":1,""010890021002"":1,""010890009011"":1,""010890109013"":1,""010730120022"":1,""010890031003"":15,""011170303151"":1,""010890019011"":9,""010890030002"":2,""010890110221"":1,""011170305021"":1,""010890026003"":2,""010890025012"":3,""010730117034"":1,""010830208022"":1,""010890031002"":2,""010890112002"":1,""010210602001"":1,""010890002022"":1,""010890017002"":65,""281059506021"":1,""010890010003"":2,""010890106222"":1,""120990059182"":1,""010890110222"":1,""010890020001"":1,""010890101003"":1,""010890018013"":1,""010890021001"":1,""010890109021"":1,""010890108001"":1,""010770106005"":1,""281059506011"":1,""010030114032"":2,""010830209001"":1,""010890027222"":1,""010730128023"":1,""010890009021"":1,""010030114051"":1,""010030109031"":1,""010030103003"":1,""010890031001"":1,""010890021003"":1,""010030114062"":4,""010890106241"":1,""281059504003"":1,""010890018011"":10,""010890019031"":5,""010890027012"":1,""010730108054"":1,""010890106223"":2,""010890111001"":1,""010210603002"":1,""010890109011"":1,""010890019012"":2,""010890113001"":1,""010890028013"":3}",1,229,99,"{""481-540"":3,""541-600"":2,""46-60"":1,""721-840"":1,""1201-1320"":7,""301-360"":6,""<20"":18,""61-120"":10,""241-300"":5,""121-180"":2,""1321-1440"":2,""841-960"":1,""1081-1200"":1,""961-1080"":3,""601-660"":3,""181-240"":2,""661-720"":3}",78,"{""0-25"":16,""76-100"":44,""51-75"":11,""26-50"":7}",708,353,14328
010950308022,2020-06-25T00:00:00-05:00,2020-06-26T00:00:00-05:00,100,2481,"{""16001-50000"":11,""0"":19,"">50000"":11,""2001-8000"":40,""1-1000"":6,""1001-2000"":3,""8001-16000"":4}","{""16001-50000"":150,"">50000"":23,""<1000"":739,""2001-8000"":23,""1001-2000"":12,""8001-16000"":208}",17,703,"{""721-1080"":21,""361-720"":19,""61-360"":10,""<60"":24,"">1080"":26}","[62,64,64,63,65,67,54,48,37,37,34,33,30,34,32,33,35,43,50,56,58,56,56,57]",8,6,"{""010950306004"":1,""010950302023"":1,""011030054051"":1,""010950311002"":1,""010950309023"":1,""010499606003"":1,""121319506023"":2,""010950308022"":86,""121319506016"":2,""010950304013"":1,""010950307024"":1,""010950309041"":1,""010890019021"":2,""010950312001"":5,""010499607002"":1,""011150402013"":1,""010550102003"":1,""120050027043"":3,""010719509003"":1,""010950302022"":1,""010950308023"":2,""120050027051"":2,""471079701022"":1,""010890106221"":1,""010950306001"":1,""010950302011"":2,""011150405013"":1,""011150402041"":2,""010950312002"":16,""011030054042"":1,""010950301002"":2,""130459105011"":1,""010730001001"":1,""130459102001"":1,""010890109013"":2,""010950308013"":14,""010719508004"":1,""120050027041"":3,""010550110021"":3,""010730049022"":1,""010950308024"":1,""010950312004"":6,""010950312003"":1,""010550104012"":2,""010550110013"":1,""120860004111"":1,""010890027222"":1,""010950306002"":2,""010950304015"":1,""011030054041"":1,""010950309031"":8,""010950308021"":1,""010950302024"":1,""010950307011"":5,""010550110012"":2,""011150404013"":1,""130459103003"":1,""120050027032"":3,""010950307012"":5,""010950309022"":2,""010950307023"":1,""010719508003"":1,""010499608001"":2,""010950310003"":1,""011150402043"":1,""120860099063"":1,""010950309021"":4,""010950309043"":2,""010950308011"":1,""010950306003"":3,""120050027042"":1,""010950308025"":5,""010950309032"":6,""010499607001"":1}",1,199,132,"{""21-45"":8,""481-540"":6,""541-600"":4,""46-60"":3,""721-840"":3,""1201-1320"":4,""301-360"":3,""<20"":20,""61-120"":10,""241-300"":2,""121-180"":4,""421-480"":3,""1321-1440"":1,""841-960"":3,""961-1080"":2,""601-660"":1,""181-240"":3,""661-720"":1,""361-420"":2}",74,"{""0-25"":20,""76-100"":48,""51-75"":23,""26-50"":4}",661,350,5044
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,
        usecols=[
                'origin_census_block_group',
                'date_range_start',
                'date_range_end',
                'device_count',
                'distance_traveled_from_home',
                'completely_home_device_count',
                'median_home_dwell_time',
                'part_time_work_behavior_devices',
                'full_time_work_behavior_devices'
                ],
                    dtype={'origin_census_block_group': str},
                ).set_index('origin_census_block_group')
```

and, later in the code, the dataframe is modified by:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda cbg: cbg[:5]).sum()
```

I don't quite understand what this line is doing precisely.
Groupby generally groups a dataframe by column, so...is it grouping the dataframe using multiple columns (0 to 5)? What is the effect of .sum() at the end?

Comment: provide an MRE please.

Comment: "is it grouping the dataframe using multiple columns (0 to 5)?" Yes. "What is the effect of .sum() at the end?" The same thing it normally does (please read the documentation).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, any chance you elaborate on this? I'm familiar with how .sum() works in general, but I'm confused about how it is applied in this case to the result of groupby

Comment: Did you try doing the `groupby` by itself? Do you understand what `sum` would do to the result that you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas' **read_csv()** will render a csv-formatted file a Pandas Dataframe.
I recommend having a ready at the Pandas' documentation, as it's very exhaustive -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

```
 usecols=[
                'origin_census_block_group',
                'date_range_start',
                'date_range_end',
                'device_count',
                'distance_traveled_from_home',
                'completely_home_device_count',
                'median_home_dwell_time',
                'part_time_work_behavior_devices',
                'full_time_work_behavior_devices'
                ],
```

The **usecols** parameter will take as input an array of desired columns and will only load the specified columns into the dataframe.

```
dtype={'origin_census_block_group': str}
```

The **dtype** parameter will take a dict as input and is to specify the data type of the values, like {'column' : datatype}

```
.set_index('origin_census_block_group')
```

**.set_index(**) will set the specificed column as the index column (ie: the first column). The usual index of Pandas' Dataframe is the row's index number, which appears as the first column of the dataframe. By setting the index, the first column now becomes the specified column. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Panda's **.groupby()** function will take a dataframe a regroup it basing on the occurrences of he values from the specified column.

That is to say, if we a dataframe such as df =

```
Fruit       Name    Quality  Count
                           
Apple       Marco    High      4
Pear        Lucia  Medium     10
Apple   Francesco     Low      3
Banana      Carlo  Medium      6
Pear        Timmy     Low      7
Apple     Roberto    High      8
Banana        Joe    High     21
Banana       Jack     Low      3
Pear          Rob  Medium      5
Apple       Louis  Medium      6
Pear     Jennifer     Low      7
Pear        Laura    High      8
```

Performing a groupby operations, such as:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x[:2]).sum()
```

Will take all the elements in the index, slice them from index 0 through index 2 and return the sum of all the corresponding values, ie:

```
Ap     21
Ba     30
Pe     37
```

Now, you might be wondering about that final **.sum()** method. If you try to print the dataframe without applying it, you'll likely get something like this:

```
<bound method GroupBy.sum of <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x109d260a0>>
```

This is because Pandas has created a **groubpy object** and does not yet now how to display it to you. Do you want to have it displayed by the number of the occurrences in the index? You'd do this:

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x[:2]).size()
```

And that would output:

```
Ap    4
Ba    3
Pe    5
```

Or maybe the sum of their respective summable values? (Which is what is done in the example)

```
df = df.groupby(lambda x: x[:2]).sum()
```

Which again, will output:

```
Ap     21
Ba     30
Pe     37
```

Notice it has taken the first two letters of the string in the index. Had it been x[:3], it would have taken the first three letters, of course.

Summing it up:

-> **.groupby()** takes the elements in the index, i.e. the first column of the dataframe and organises the dataframe in groups relating to the index

-> The input you have given to groubpy is an anonymous function, i.e. **lambda** function, slicing from index 0 through 5 of its mapped input

-> You may choose how to have the results of groubpy by appending the methos **.sum()** or **.size()** to a groubpy object

I also recommend reading about Python's lambda functions:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused because, in general, you need to specify which column you have to group the rows by, while in this case it is grouping (after the slicing done by lambda function) automatically on the index column. That part I completely missed at the beginning.

Comment: I am glad I could help Carlo, buona giornata! :D

Answer (score 2):

If you run your code exactly as you wrote it (both the creation of df and the groupby) you can see the result. I print first couple of columns of the output of `groupby`

```
         device_count    distance_traveled_from_home
-----  --------------  -----------------------------
01053              49                            626
01073             139                           2211
01089              78                           1934
01095             100                           2481
```

What happens here is the function `lambda cbg: cbg[:5]` is applied to each of the index values (strings that look like numbers in column `origin_census_block_group`). As a side, note the statement

```
...
dtype={'origin_census_block_group': str},
```

when creating the df, so somebody went into trouble to make sure they are actually `str`

So the function is applied to string like `'010539707003'` and returns a substring which is the first 5 characters of that string:

```
'010539707003'[:5]
```

produces

```
'01053'
```

so I assume there are multiple keys that share the first 5 characters (in the actual file -- the snippet has them all unique so not very interesting) and all these rows are grouped together

Then `.sum()` is applied to each numerical column of each group and returns, well, the column sum per each groupby key. This is what you see in my output in column `'device_count'` and so on.

Hope this is clear now

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I said to another answer, I was getting confused because in general you have to specify the column to use for grouping, while in this case it seems it is automatically using the index one. Also, I didn't know how to print the output of groupby alone (still don't actually), so I didn't understand what .sum() was operating on.

Comment: @Carlo to understand what `groupby` does I find it helpful to look at the result as such `for key, group in df.groupby('First'):
    print (key, group)` here 'First' is the name of the column you groupby